# Invalid characters in JSON.parse(result.responseText);

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets, extjs

I am returning a string that looks like this:

```
[{"name":"John","age":"21","gender":"m"}]
```

and then do:

```
JSON.parse(result.responseText);
```

to put data in grid control. It works fine in FF. In IE my string looks like this:

```
[{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":\"21\",\"gender\":\"m\"}]
```

and slashes aren't being processed and my `JSON.parse(result.responseText)` fails giving me invalid characters error. Why do I have different responses between browsers and how do I fix this issue? I am posting full call.

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'PersonServlet',
        method: 'POST',                   
        params :{'id': id},

        success: function ( result, request ) {
            resultData = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
            store.removeAll();
            store.add(resultData);

        },
        failure: function ( result, request ) {
            resultData = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
        }   
    });
```

Comment: IE8's JSON.parse doesn't like to parse array literals, only Objects. You can likely do something like wrap your array in a single prop object: {data:[{"name":"John","age":"21","gender":"m"}]}, and say resultData = JSON.parse(result.responseText).data;

Comment: well I tried with returned data like this "{data:[{'name':'John','age':'21','gender':'m'}]}" but resultData = JSON.parse(result.responseText); call isn't working and giving me an error JSON is undetified.

Comment: Could i just clean responseText to replace backslashes to empty space? That will work but is that a good solution?

Comment: perhaps, but im not sure why\how those backslasher are there in the first place, if your response looks like the first code box...

Comment: Try replace symbol(") for symbol(') on your response. Prefer, after send to extjs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.JSON 
instead of the native JSON parser. Hopefully you will get more consistent behavior.